# flex path addition doesnt work

Tags: c, path, windows-xp, lex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to use flex and have installed in c:\gnuwin32\bin have added such to PATH as well as c:\dev-cpp\bin.

Calls to gcc work no problem, but calls to flex don't unless I am in the c:\gnuwin32\bin directory, which means asking gcc to compile with lex.yy.c fails as it can't find some external lex functions like yywrap().

Here is what my path is currently the last two items or the ones in question.
Does the last path item need to be terminated by a semicolon? I'm at a loss as to why it's not working otherwise..

[image: echo path]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to the PATH concatenation.

Gcc does not find the flex runtime library at link time you have to add a -L option to specify its location and add the libfl.a

Something like

```
gcc -o target *.o -L <path> -lfl
```

You can also disable the yywrap feature by using the following flex option

```
 %option noyywrap
```

See the [FAQ entry in the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/I-get-an-error-about-undefined-yywrap_0028_0029_002e.html)

Comment: this may solve the compilation but doesnt explain why I cannot run flex without being in the flex bin

Comment: if you type the full path of flex.exe does it work. If yes you have too check the tipo in the PATH variable.

Comment: Have edit picture in question to show, as far as I can tell, there is no typo

Comment: If you type c:\gnuwin32\bin\flex.exe your-flex. Does it work ?